# How can I get a prepopulated inventory field to show only the InventoryID and not the description (Acumatica)

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom graph that was built for us by Acumatica; it uses a PXProjection called by the primary graph's PXSelectJoin to select data and populate the fields.

A couple of fields are inventory ID fields:

```
    #region KitComponentID
    public abstract class kitComponentID : IBqlField { }
    [StockItem(DisplayName = "Kit Component ID", IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(INKitSpecStkDet.compInventoryID))]
    public virtual int? KitComponentID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region KitInventoryID
    public abstract class kitInventoryID : IBqlField { }
    [SOLineInventoryItem(DisplayName = "Kit ID", BqlField = typeof(SOLine.inventoryID))]
    public virtual int? KitInventoryID { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

These fields are not user editable, only for display.  We would like to have them display only the InventoryCD, not the CD and description.

Is there a different way I can define my fields so that they are still automatically populated but display only the InventoryCD?

Comment: Could you add an example with data so that it will be clear what you want to achieve?Both of these attributes are used in the SOOrderEntry and INReceiptEntry and there the Inventory ID field is showing only Inventory CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the screen editor, the field should have a drop-down of DisplayMode. By default, I believe it's Hint (which is Key + Description), Value (which is just key), and Text (which is Description.)

If you change the DisplayMode to Value, it should give you what you want.